# testCafe How to add headers to the home page url

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, single-sign-on, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have an application which is launched successfully by adding or modifying request headers ( something like single sign on). When we have to test it we use a chrome plugin like this one :https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en   to add custom headers and paste the home page url say: "https://student.com" in the browser url and request picks the modified headers and once validated internally by the app, the home page is rendered on browser. If a user does not have access, a error page is rendered.

I am trying to test this application using testCafe and looking to see if there is a way to add headers to the "navigateTo('url')"  function in testcafe. I thought I could accomplish this with customer hook explained here: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/creating-a-custom-http-request-hook.html

This is what I have so far
**hook declaration**

```
    class myRequestHook extends RequestHook {
        constructor () {
            super();
        }

        async onRequest (e) {
            e.requestOptions.headers['UserName'] = 'User';
            e.requestOptions.headers['pwd'] = 'User';        
        }

        async onResponse (e) {

        }
    }

const customHook = new myRequestHook('https://student.com/app/home', {
    includeHeaders: true,
    includeBody: true
});
```

And this how my test uses it

```
fixture`Getting Started`
      .page('http://student.com')
      .requestHooks(customHook);    

test.only('My first test', async t => {
    await t.navigateTo('https://student.com/app/home');
    await page_student.click_studentLink();
    await t
        .expect(await page_student.getText_title_student()).eql('John Smith')
});
```

The home page still displays an error which means the headers appendage wasn't successful. Could someone point me where I am going wrong

Also, is there a way I can check that my request is actually carrying my custom header - username and password along with the URL. It will be helpful if I can actually debug to see if the request is being carried out with the custom headers.

Any pointers will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your `requestHook` and your test seem valid. I've debugged the latest `testcafe-hammerhead` (the core of the TestCafe) version and it works as expected. Besides, I found that the `https://student.com/app/home` page does not exist and browser returns 404 error. Could you please describe your scenario in more detail, since I don't see an issue with request hooks at this moment.